# How do you access the id of a Django model inside the model object?

Tags: python, django

I have a simple model that I would like to include the hash of the id of the model in:

```
class pick(models.Model):
    id_hash = models.TextField(default=hashlib.md5(id).hexdigest())
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    buy_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    buy_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    buy_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    def hash(self):
        return hashlib.md5(str(self.id)).hexdigest()
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {} {} {}".format(self.symbol,self.buy_datetime,self.buy_price,self.sell_price,self.buy_quantity, self.current_price)
```

of course for id_hash, I don't have access to `id` inside the model class. is there any way that I can try to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I don't understand the question fully. Are you trying to say that the `id_hash` will be auto calculated?

Comment: I want the hash of the id to be saved right next to the id in the database table

Comment: you see, I want to search for a record for an id_hash and I don't want to search through all pick objects by putting them all in ram, instead I want to use the sql search which is only possible by putting the hash in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `save` method, since `id` is auto generated from database you have to save atleast twice -

```
class pick(models.Model):
    id_hash = models.TextField(default="")
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    buy_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    buy_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    buy_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    def hash(self):
        return hashlib.md5(str(self.id)).hexdigest()
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {} {} {}".format(self.symbol,self.buy_datetime,self.buy_price,self.sell_price,self.buy_quantity, self.current_price)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            # for python < 3.0 super(pick, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 
            self.id_hash = self.hash()
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            # for python < 3.0 super(pick, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but there is one other solution, if you only required the `id_hash` for using with python only but not search with it in db, then you do not need to save it, you could use a `property` for the hash value like this -

```
    @property
    def id_hash(self):
        return hashlib.md5(str(self.id)).hexdigest()
```

Comment: thanks but for the second option, would I be able to search through id_hashes at the same speed and using the same amount of ram as it I was searching for id_hashes?

Comment: nope, the second option will not work for SQL, because the `id_hash` is a property not db column, so the check will be done in ram.

Comment: so I couldn't search by id_hash using the second option? or I could only do it using a standard python loop?

Comment: yup... you can search in a python loop. but not with SQL in database

Comment: it says that super requires at least 1 argument?

Comment: yes I am using 2.7 sorry I should have specified that

Comment: Updated... use the one for python < 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You want to override the create method for the model, so that the id_hash is written after the initial save.  I'm presuming that you don't want to write id_hash more than once.  For example, maybe something like

```
class PickManager(models.Manager):
    def create(**kwargs):
        instance = super(PickManager, self).create(**kwargs)
        instance.id_hash = hashlib.md5(instance.id).hexdigest()
        instance.save()

class Pick(models.Model):
    id_hash = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ...
    objects = PickManager()
```

Also, you should capitalize your model number (Pick) and probably use **unicode** instead of **str**.